# Multiple files upload with FileReader

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to upload 3 photos and preview them. It works fine with one, but when I use this loop it obviously will read only the last file because k will not change.

```
function readMany(input)
{
    var k = 0 ;
    for (k=0;k<input.files.length;k++)
    {

      console.log(k); // ** ok - print 1,2,3

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e)
      {

        var div = document.getElementById( imagePreviews[k] );
        $(div).css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
        $(div).hide();
        $(div).fadeIn(850);

        console.log(k); // ** print 3 times the number 3.



      }
      uploadedProductPhotos=input.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[k]);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `let` solves this problem :

```
 for (let k=0;k<input.files.length;k++)
```

So that `k` will keep its state.